# How to set custom systemd network configuration files search path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, embedded-linux, systemd

I have a use case where I want to set a systemd-network configuration files in a user defined path.

By default the path is /etc/systemd/network/example.network. Is there any possibility to keep my example.network config file in a different folder for ex:/home/user/network/example.network and to make the systemd to look for .network files in this custom path.

Comment: So just symlink it.

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't seems to be working. The simulink is destroyed and two empty config .network files were appeared on boot. I don't know if it is the default behavior

Comment: I would rather copy the files to the default location on boot and it seems to be working. But I'm wondering if I can have  a better solution